# How to convert a string look like an array

Tags: javascript

I make a get request to URL "http://cafef3.mediacdn.vn/v2/kby/ccf4d584-4b06-4370-acff-c0241b4ad0d6/kby.js". It is a javascript file and I get a string "var oc=[object_1, object_2]".

How can I create a new array based on the string above? e.g. let newArray = [object_1, object_2]
Thank!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's for browser.. you could create a new script tag (so that the content of the javascript file will be parsed) and then assign the new variable from there.
Here is some code for reference:

```
const newScriptTag = document.createElement('script')
newScriptTag.textContent = content; // content is the value of the js file (var oc... )
document.body.append(newScriptTag)
let newArray = oc;
// then remove the script tag
document.body.removeChild(scriptTag)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could get rid go the prefix and suffix of your string using something like:

```
let result = 'var oc=["object_1", "object_2"];';
result = result.replace('var oc=','');//to remove the variable definition from the start
result = result.slice(0,-1);//to remove ';' at the end. You can use this, because strings are arrays of characters
```

And then use:

```
result = JSON.parse(result);//this should give you a nice array with your objects in it
```

You can find references for the methods I mentioned from a couple of different sources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

**EDIT**:
That last part with `JSON.parse()` would work if the return for your request was a valid JSON. but it's not, that's JS code, representing the definition of an object. To parse that, you could use `eval()`. But you should exercise caution and only use that in strings that return from trustworthy sources, since that could inadvertently execute malicious code inside your code.
That said, the last line of code to solve your problem would be something like:

```
result = eval(result)
console.log(result);
```

Thankfully, there's a better way to do it using `Function()` like so:

```
result = Function('"use strict";return (' + result + ')')
console.log(result());
```

You can read the reference from these two last ways of parsing code as string in here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!

Comment: "[object_1,object_2]" is not valid json, it should be "["object_1","object_2"]"

Comment: @Ufuk I'm sure he meant javascript object literals.. dont take it literally

Comment: Yeah, it's not. But if you follow the url that Xuân provided in the question, you'll see that the request does provide valid json. We used object_X just to shorten the answer. I'll update my answer in any case to provide working code. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: No provided url is not valid json, objects dont have " " in that data

Comment: Take this part as example and try your code in console : `var oc=[{i:0,c:"@BCC",m:"Bitcoin cash (Bitcoin cash)",o:"Bitcoin cash (Bitcoin cash)",san:8}]`

Comment: I don't think that's going to be a problem, since that string is going to be returned from a request that might already treat these characters with proper escaping structures. If not it can be escaped in the code using the same methods I pointed out.

Comment: Go to provided link, open console write this : `let result = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerText`, then try your own method, it will give an error

Comment: If it treats these characters with proper escaping structures then how it is converted in the html as a non-valid JSON ?

Comment: So... I did some testing and it actually doesn't work. Not because of the quotes inside the string, but because the string returned is an object. And objects are not valid json strings. Given that, I'll be updating the answer for using a more appropriate approach.

Answer (score -2):

Turn each object into an array using `Object.entries` and merge the arrays.

```js
const obj1 = { "1": 500, "2": 15, "5": 4, "4": 480, "10": 87 };
const obj2 = { "1": 500, "2": 15, "5": 4, "4": 480, "10": 87 };
const myArray = Object.entries(obj1).concat(Object.entries(obj2));;
console.log(myArray);
```